# How to change input tag to textarea tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I am using spring to connect .html file and controller. Now, I have . But I want to change it to be a text area tag. I'm using .html file and not a .jsp file.

Comment: Not so clear as question. Can you explain it better?

Comment: If you are not using a jsp file, why is the jsp tag in the question? You should only use tags that are relevant to your problem. It would also help if you posted your code attempt to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The code for input text is :

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
```

You can convert it to textarea as below :

```
<textarea name="field1" id="field1"> 

</textarea>
```